# Python Pelican order menu items

Tags: python, html, css, pelican

This is a followup question based on the answer provided by jcollado over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18520046/how-can-i-control-the-order-of-pages-from-within-a-pelican-article-category). I setup my menu as he described but now I am unable to actually add my active css to the active item.

```
DISPLAY_PAGES_ON_MENU = False
DISPLAY_CATEGORIES_ON_MENU = False
MENUITEMS = (
    ('HOME', '/'),
    ('ABOUT', '/pages/about.html'),
    ('JOURNAL', '/category/journal.html'),
    ('CONTACT', '/pages/contact.html'),
)
```

When I go back and remove the display pages and categories on menu and menu items. The menu's active css works but then my menu has terrible ordering.

Is there some way that I can order the pages without breaking my css?

I have pages defined as markdown files. If my menu was only pages I could order by a custom attribute. The problem is that there are 3 pages and 1 category, the category is based on a folder inside the `/content/category`

Is it possible to overcome this obstacle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelican 3.5, which was just released this week, includes a new `PAGE_ORDER_BY` setting. This was discussed at length in [issue #420](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican/issues/420) and is briefly mentioned in Pelican Docs > Settings.

If you want the pages to appear at `example.com/yourpage`, use the appropriate [URL settings](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/latest/settings.html#url-settings):

```
PAGE_URL = '{slug}'
PAGE_SAVE_AS = '{slug}'
```

Comment: Hi Justin I followed this but this still leaves me a bit confused. I am basically trying to make sure that I have clean url paths. So instead of going to domain.com/pages/test.html I can just go to domain.com/test

Comment: I have no idea how that question relates to your original question, but I have updated the answer to include the information you requested. I think perhaps you might be better served by asking your question via the [Pelican IRC channel](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/latest/contribute.html#the-pelican-irc-channel), where you can get more interactive assistance.